# react routing - rendering error (single page application)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hi I am learning react and trying to create SPA, but internal pages are not rendered.

Only  is rendered, it's not rendering Internal components like  &

[image]

**Unable to find exact problem**

I have tried multiple combinations for Route path like

```
<Route path="/about" component={About}/>
<Route path="about" component={About}/>
```

**My Complete Code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
// import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'; 
import About from './About';
import Home from './Home';
import Repos from './Repos';
import AboutChild from './AboutChild';

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <menu>
                    <ul>
                        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="/repos">Repos</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                </menu>
            </div>            
        );
    }
}


render((<Router>
            <App>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
                <Route path="/repos" component={Repos}/>
            </App>
</Router>), document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Component versions from package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.0",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1"
  }
```

Comment: did that answer work?

Comment: @demon - Yes it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your App component in render you need to return children props. Try this

```
  render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <menu>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/repos">Repos</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </menu>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>            
    );
}
```

You can also remove constructor, because you don't use it in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
```